# Making certain form fields inline with label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

By default all of my input fields are 100% in width. For one of my form fields I need the label to be inline with the input field. The rest of them can all be stacked. I tried the following but it is still pushing the input field down below its label:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="fieldLabel1" runat="server" Text="Field label 1" AssociatedControlID="ntxtFieldLabel1"></asp:Label>
        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="ntxtFieldLabel1" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control"></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
    </div>                                                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `col-*-*` class tags in order to set the amount of cols you want.

For example you set the label for 2 columns using the class `col-md-2`.
For input elements, the best practice will be using a parent `div` container.
Then on this parent you set the amount of columns using the class `col-md-10`.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="BrandId">Merk</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="BrandId">Merk</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See my fiddle with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/0vp9aL61/